# How do I make an HTML table inline

Tags: html, css, html-table

In HTML I want to display a small table as part of a paragraph. One way to do that is this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Before 
      <table style="display:inline;"><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr> <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr> </table>
      After
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

which produces this nice layout:

```
       a b
Before     After
       c d
```

which is exactly what I want.

But it seems rather silly to me to use a table inside a table when what I really want is to use a table inside a paragraph. However, if I try using this HTML:

```
<p>
  Before 
    <table style="display:inline;"><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr> <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr></table>
  After
</p>
```

I get this ugly layout:

```
Before
a b
    After
c d
```

I've tried using various different display styles, but none seem to do what I want.

Am I forced to use the table-within-table code, or am I missing something?

Comment: what broswer (and version) renders the second example as you have shown? [not mine =)]

Comment: I should have mentioned that my Doctype is XHTML 1.0 Strict. The problem does not appear with HTML 4.01 Transitional.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Making the paragraph `display: inline;` works for me. But, if you have multiple paragraphs, you will have to add a `<br />` after each of them.

Comment: I should have mentioned that my Doctype is XHTML 1.0 Strict. Your solution works fine (even without <br/>) in XMTHML 1.0 Strict; but I was hoping that I could achieve what I wanted without modifying the style of the surrounding paragraph. But perhaps I can't.

Comment: I don't think you can, as paragraphs are not inline elements by default.

Answer (score 33):

You could use the following css:

```
display:inline-table
```

onnly IE7 and below don't support this property. Probably wrapping the table in a span with `zoom:1` applied to it could help IE7.

Comment: This should be the preferred answer.  It does not require any outer element context.

Answer (score 6):

I'm using Chrome browser on Linux and I am able to get this to work by adding `display:inline-table` to both the paragraph (p) and table tags:

```
<p style="display:inline-table;">
  Before
  <table style="display:inline-table;"><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr> <tr><td>c</td><td>d</td></tr></table>
  After
</p>
```

Just checked Firefox on Linux and it seems to work there too.

FYI: Removing either of the two `display:inline-table` styles gave undesirable formatting.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose that you have a good reason to use a table here instead of css. You can get the effect using a single table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">Before</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td>b</td>
    <td rowspan="2">After</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That will not work for me because the "Before" and "After" text are actually several lines of text and the small table appears in the middle of the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't work because `<table>` shouldn't be a child of `<p>`

(you can try the W3C validator to see more about this error)

simply replace `<p>` with `<div>`