# Making an HTML Table Inline

Tags: css, html-table

I'm trying to put two tables side by side:

```
<table class="inline">
</table>
<table class="inline">
</table>
```

But none of the values I assign to inline's display property from inline-table to inline to inline-block work so I'm stumped and would appreciate any advice. I only found one other relevant question: [How do I make an HTML table inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457319/how-do-i-make-an-html-table-inline) and unfortunately the solutions didn't work.

Comment: Can you show us more of your HTML like the contents of the table?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11690223/617996

Comment: Both inline-block and inline-table work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/gkcuA/

Comment: Show us code (and fiddle) of a reproducible case where `inline-table` doesn't work for you. And tell us which versions of IE you've to be compatible with.

Comment: If you are trying to style your tables in a css file, then please include your css code as well.

Comment: Sorry that the question didn't have enough information. The styling in CSS currently looks like: .inline{display:inline}, the tables contain this html: <tr><td>Random Movie Title</td></tr><tr><td>Random Movie Title</td></tr> etc for 5 rows of movie titles each. I know this layout is really simple and couple be done without tables more easily but I'd like to use tables for this example.

Answer (score 3):

By default, tables are block level elements and you need to change the display property to get two or more tables per line, for example:

```
<table class="inline">
    <tr><td>First table row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>First table row 2</td></tr>
</table>
<table class="inline">
    <tr><td>Second table row 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Second table row 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

with the following CSS:

```
.inline { 
    outline: 1px solid blue;
    width: 49%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You can also use `inline-table`, both give the same results.  If you don't set the width, each table will determine a minimum width to fit the content.  If you set the width, you can make the two tables the same width, which may be desirable.

If you try `display: inline`, the table widths will shrink to fit the content, which may be preferable in some applications.  In this case, the width setting is ignored.

I have shown the three cases in the following fiddle.

Fiddle reference: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/m4fdG/

Answer (score 1):

It should not be:

```
<table class="inline">
</table>
<table class="inline">
</table>
```

It should be:

```
<table style="display:inline">
</table>
<table style="display:inline">
</table>
```

Comment: Inline styling is better than using classes? Really?

Comment: I agree, preferable to use a style sheet.  More importantly, display `inline` gives a different layout than `inline-block`.

Comment: Nope never implied it was... No css is given so I'm working with what was given. A reason why it might not work is because it is being declared improperly, e.g. class="inline", instead of style="display:inline" is what I'm saying.