# Place tables next to each other without using 'float'

Tags: html, css, html-table, html-email

I am trying to find out a solution of adding tables next to each other without using 'float:left;'. I am using the code for an email template and 'float' doesn't work on Outlook and some other email clients.

I have tried everything I could think of, searched the forum and all over the web but I am unable to find a solution.

Here's the code I am using:

```
<table width="155" height="155" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff" class="main-content" style="float:left;margin-bottom:20px;">
  <tbody>
      <tr>         
         <td><img style="border:0;" align="none" height="113" width="166" src="<?php echo $post_thumbnail ?>"  /></td>
         <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" width="35" style="color:#f4f4f4;">T</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>        
     <td style="font-family:arial;font-size:13px;font-weight:bold !important;line-height:17px;padding:10px 10px 0;"><strong>Text</strong></td>
     <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" width="35" style="color:#f4f4f4;">T</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>        
    <td width="155" style="color: #666;font-size:13px;padding:0 10px 15px;">  
        <a style="background-color:#ac0003; color:#ffffff; border:1px solid #660b0e;cursor: pointer; display: block; font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; margin: 0 auto;margin-top:10px;padding: 2px 11px;;text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff; font-weight:bold;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;" href="<?php echo $post->guid ?>">Text</a>
     </td>
     <td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" width="35" style="color:#f4f4f4;">T</td>
      </tr>


      </tbody>

</table>
```

Help!

Comment: Hey, First result in a search, is that helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367542/in-outlook-html-email-float-does-not-work

Comment: Thanks @RonniSkansing! I have already gone through the guides from MailChimp, Campaign Monitor, etc, but they don't have something specific written to give me a solution.

Comment: http://www.email-standards.org/ it does not give another solutions either, but a good place to check what specific vendors are able to.

Answer (score 1):

You can try giving the table elements a display of inline. They should then line up next to each other.

Comment: Some tips on that here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457319/how-do-i-make-an-html-table-inline

Comment: That still doesn't fix the problem on Outlook.

Comment: kat_indo, i highly recommend giving this article a quick read. it should help clear up any confusion you're encountering with outlook.  Link: http://www.sitepoint.com/code-html-email-newsletters-2/

Comment: Thanks @GraySpectrum. I have already read too many guidelines but none of them provides a solution.

Comment: What version of outlook are you using?

Answer (score 0):

User display: inline-block; instead of float:left;

Answer (score 0):

For html email you should be using `align="left"` instead.

[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17674172/equivalent-to-float-in-outlook/17677304#17677304)